# Как создать новый jpg/png из обрезанного старого файла на java Script

Tags: javascript, imageview, base64

Я загружаю файл на страницу.
Получаю координаты для того что бы его обрезать.
Как мне создать новый файл с нужными размерами и записать строку base64 c новыми размерами ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант.

```
  var canvas = object['querySelector']('canvas')
  ctx['drawImage'](image, 0, 0, naturalWidth, naturalHeight,sx ,sy , dWidth, dHeight)
  canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream')
```

Есть ещё сложный но он вряд ли понадобится.